# How to extract a specific key-value pair from a nested list without any label in Response body using Rest-Assured along with Java?

Tags: json, rest, testing, httpresponse, rest-assured

Here is an example of Nested List from which I need to extract the highlighted "**userId**" and "**oneAccountId**" values from the Response body: (There are two Keys with "userId" tag at different levels in the hierarchy from which I need the value for the outermost one at index[1].)

```
[
    {
        "userId": 4813,
        "oneAccountId": 20785114,
        "userOptions": [
            {
                "userOptionsId": null,
                "userId": null,
            },
            {
                "userOptionsId": null,
                "userId": null,
            },
            {
                "userOptionsId": null,
                "userId": null,
            },
            {
                "userOptionsId": null,
                "userId": null,
            },
            {
                "userOptionsId": 16093,
                "userId": 4813,
            }
        ],
        "accessLocations": null
    },
    {
        "**userId**": 56725,
        "**oneAccountId**": 66443583,
        "userOptions": [
            {
                "userOptionsId": null,
                "userId": null,
            },
            {
                "userOptionsId": null,
                "userId": null,
            },
            {
                "userOptionsId": null,
                "userId": null,
            },
            {
                "userOptionsId": 27135,
                "userId": 56725,
            },
            {
                "userOptionsId": 27145,
                "userId": 56725,
            }
        ],
        "accessLocations": null
    },
    {
        "userId": 21455,
        "oneAccountId": 35993484,
        "userOptions": [
            {
                "userOptionsId": 29253,
                "userId": 21455,
            },
            {
                "userOptionsId": null,
                "userId": null,
            },
            {
                "userOptionsId": 29023,
                "userId": 21455,
            },
            {
                "userOptionsId": 3843,
                "userId": 21455,
            },
            {
                "userOptionsId": 3615,
                "userId": 21455,
            }
        ],
        "accessLocations": null
    },
    {
        "userId": 52903,
        "oneAccountId": 61477703,
        "userOptions": [
            {
                "userOptionsId": null,
                "userId": null
            },
            {
                "userOptionsId": null,
                "userId": null,
            },
            {
                "userOptionsId": null,
                "userId": null,
            },
            {
                "userOptionsId": 24303,
                "userId": 52903,
            },
            {
                "userOptionsId": 24313,
                "userId": 52903,
            }
        ],
        "accessLocations": null
    }
]
```

In my Postman Request "Test Script", I used following Snippet to extract the desired values and store it as Local Variables:

```
const response = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.environment.set("userId", response[1].userId);
pm.environment.set("oneAccountId", response[1].oneAccountId);
```

And for my Rest-Assured framework, I am trying to using this particular line of code to extract the values: (**This is not working though and is returning NULL as Output for userId and oneAccountId**)

```
@Test (dataProvider = "endPoints")
public void get_users_associated_to_a_particular_compcode(String endPoints) 
{
    Response response = given().
                    header("Content-Type", "application/json").
                    header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken).
                    get(endPoints).
                    then().
                    statusCode(200).
                    contentType(ContentType.JSON).
                    extract().response();
   JsonPath extractValue = response.jsonPath();
   String userID = extractValue.getList("userId").get(1).toString();
   String oneAccountID = extractValue.getList("oneAccountId").get(1).toString();
}
```

Can anyone please suggest the correct way to extract the desired values using "*RESTAssured Java-TestNG*" framework?

Comment: Could you add full code, I don't know `extractValue` here? Are you sure that `extractValue` is the whole response.

Comment: Hey @lucas-nguyen-17, Sorry about that. I just edited my post and added the entire Test block to it. I hope this turns out to be helpful to you. Thank you for responding.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, except `userId` and `oneAccountId` is int, not String. E.g `int userId = extractValue.getInt("[1].userId");`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Object> map = RestAssured
            .get("https://run.mocky.io/v3/69df392d-7bf7-4a87-afd3-da7d26e3f434")
            .body()
            .jsonPath()
            .getMap("[1]");
    System.out.println(map.get("userId"));
    System.out.println(map.get("oneAccountId"));
}
```

Comment: Hey @Alexey R., Thank you for responding. I will try out the solution you suggested.